# Serving identical double-sized images to retina display computers AND non-retina computers?

Tags: html, image, retina-display

On my website, I have a 1300x200 image that I am forcing down to 650x100 using the simple `width=650px` parameter in the `img` tag. What happens when a retina Mac/iPhone/iPad user views my site. Will they see the full quality 1300x200 image, or will the quality artificially be reduced by half?

As far as whether or not this is efficient, it's just a 50k PNG. My site is otherwise mostly vectored with text/CSS. You could argue this is more efficient than messing with browser-agent detecting Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok folks, I went about answering it myself, and yes, if you use the `width` tag to half-size an `img` in HTML, the retina browser will display the full sized image.

I displayed the 1300x200 image half-sized using `width` on the top, and the plain 650x100 image on the bottom. Zoomed in using Safari on iOS 6.

[image: example one]
[image: example two]